# SquidGuard produces lots of segfaults

Tags: 14.04, segmentation-fault, squid

on my machine with Ubuntu 14.04 I'm using Squid3 (3.3.8-1ubuntu6.6) with SquidGuard (1.5-2) and the Shalla blacklist.
I can compile the blacklist files into its db-files without any issues but when running I keep seeing lots of segfault messages in /var/log/syslog like this:
May 24 08:54:09 mymachine kernel: [590623.119654] squidGuard[587]: segfault at d8 ip 00007fd93244ad42 sp 00007ffd8d49b900 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7fd932367000+1bb000]
I searched the web but didn't find any suitable answer.
Any ideas?
Cheers
Stefan